# SqlBulkCopy from Oracle to SQL Server with DataReader is slow (100k to 20M)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, etl, sqlbulkcopy

I have been working on sending a table from Oracle to SQL Server with `SqlBulkCopy`.

I am doing it by reading with a datareader from oracle and then streaming into SQL Server. I have tried with different batch sizes (500, 5000, 50000) with a test sample of the first 100000 rows. (the table has about 20M).

Right now with these different batch sized the 100k takes about 10 minutes. I understand that this is quite slow.

The table structure is the following (no indexes, no anything, clean table created for receiving the data):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROJECT_COST_HISTORY](
    [PROJECT_ID] [numeric](15, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PERIOD_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PROJECT_NUMBER] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [PROJECT_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PROJECTFUNC_CURRENCY] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [TRANSACTION_TYPE] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [TASK_NUMBER] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EXPENDITURE_ITEM_ID] [numeric](15, 0) NULL,
    [EVENT_ID] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [TRANSACTION_SOURCE] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [EXPENDITURE_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [JOB_FUNCTION] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [ACCOUNT_NUMBER] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [CURRENT_WEEK_ENDING_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [TRANSACTION_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CORRECTION_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [PROJECT_ACCOUNTING_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [RESOURCE_TYPE] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [EMPLOYEE_VENDOR_NUMBER] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [EMPLOYEE_VENDOR_NAME] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [BILLABLE_FLAG] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ACCOUNTING_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CHARGED_PU] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ASSIGNED_PU] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ORIGINAL_WEEKEND_DATE] [nvarchar](18) NULL,
    [PO_NUMBER] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ACCOUNTING_TRANSFER_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [WORKHOUR_FLAG] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [LEGALENTITY] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [BURDENED_COST] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [RAW_COST] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [FRINGE_COST] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [HOURS] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [WORKSHARE_FLAG] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [WORKSHARE_BURDENED_COST] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [WORKSHARE_RAW_COST] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [DOCUMENT_CURRENCY_CODE] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [DOCUMENT_BURDENED_COST] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [DOCUMENT_RAW_COST] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [TRANSACTION_FRINGE] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [EXPENDITURE_ENDING_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_KEY] [numeric](15, 0) NULL,
    [PROJECT_KEY] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [INSERT_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [UPDATE_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [INVOICE_NUMBER] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PERSON_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [COST_LINENUMBER] [numeric](15, 0) NULL,
    [GID_WORKSHARE_FLAG] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [PROJECT_STATUS] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [REV_HOURS] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and my code is:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DbInsert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");

            string oracleConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=usqts0-scan01)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=BIDSITH)));User Id=ukieapps;Password=ukieapps;";
            string sql = @"select pp.project_id, pc.*
                        from PROJECT_COST_history pc
                        inner join rt_pa_projects pp on pc.project_number = pp.segment1 and rownum <100000";

            string sqlServerConnectionString = "Server=glasql01t.europe.jacobs.com;Database=JEG_PROG_TABLES_R12;User Id=webaccount;Password=webaccount-123;Integrated Security=False;";

            var dt = GetDataWithDataReader(oracleConnectionString, sql);

            InsertData(dt, sqlServerConnectionString);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IDataReader GetDataWithDataReader(
            string connectionString,
            string sql
        )
        {
            var timer = new Stopwatch();

            Console.WriteLine("Reading From Oracle Started");

            var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

            connection.Open();
            var command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            timer.Start();

            IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            timer.Stop();

            TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
            string timeTakenMessage = "Time taken: " + timeTaken.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff");

            Console.WriteLine($"Reading From Oracle Finished, {timeTakenMessage}");

            return reader;
        }
        
        private static void InsertData(IDataReader dt, string sqlServerConnectionString)
        {
            var timer = new Stopwatch();

            //string sql = "Truncate table DBO.PROJECT_COST_HISTORY;" + Environment.NewLine;
            string connectionString = sqlServerConnectionString;
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                //using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                //{
                //    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //}

                using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DBO.PROJECT_COST_HISTORY";
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
                    bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting copy to sql server");
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;

                    timer.Start();

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);

                    timer.Stop();

                    TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;

                    var timeTakenMessage = "Time taken: " + timeTaken.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff");

                    Console.WriteLine($"Copy finished Finished, {timeTakenMessage}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I could check to make it faster? I understand that a datareader should be  the fastest way.

I have also tried doing it via openquery to the Oracle DB via linked server, but is also taking a lot of time. (as per what I read for example here: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/faster-sql-bulk-inserts-with-csharp#sql-bulk-copy ). and I have also tried it by reading into a DataTable instead of data reader, but whilst the insert to sql server is quite fast, the filling of the DataTable is slow (whole process takes around 15 minutes).

I'm open to any suggestions here as I've been trying as much as I can and I think it should be possible to do it better. (also advise in regards of understanding if the bottleneck is in Oracle reading or SQL Server inserting would be greatly appreciated).

Also if it help, here is a screenshot of the explain plan of the following query:

```
Select Pp.Project_Id,
       Pc.*
From Project_Cost_History Pc
     Inner Join Rt_Pa_Projects Pp On Pc.Project_Number = Pp.Segment1
```

[image]

Comment: If filling the DataTable is slow, the DataReader will be as well. I suggest you focus on tuning/index tuning of the source Oracle query.

Comment: what tunning could be done to it? is a select without conditions (I want to copy the entire table) I put the rownum just for testing a smaller sample

Comment: We only know the information provided in your question, where you have both JOINs and a WHERE clause. If your query is different, I suggest you include that in your question. Indexes may help.

Comment: I have edited the query as it will run (except the rownum condition just for testing now) the project_id field used is index in that table

Comment: How long does the Oracle Query run from SQLPLUS? Do you have indexes on the joined columns? Have you looked at the EXPLAIN PLAN? You mentioned it uses an index on project_id but you are joining on project_number.

Comment: I don't really know how to use sqlplus to connect (the oracle db is not on my machine and I can't remote to it) I'll look into this, however is a big server, it shouldn't be the bottleneck, I'll investigate further

Comment: I suggested SQLPLUS but you can use any query tool to run the query independently of your application as a sanity check.

Comment: A simple way to determine the location of the bottleneck is to leave out the bulk insert -- simply hook the reader into a `while (dt.Read()) {}` dummy loop. This gives you the plain time needed to execute the query in Oracle and stream it client-side (which depends on both query speed and network bandwidth). If this takes much less than the total time needed to insert, the bottleneck should be on the SQL Server end, if it takes as much time, it's the Oracle part that needs speeding up.

Comment: would you be able to help me understand a explain plan? I have ran one with sqlDeveloper

Comment: Add the pan to your question so folks can take a look.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn right away :) is there

Comment: The parallel plan is doing full scan of the table and index for the hash join. I would expect the query to be expensive if run from Sql Developer as well. Perhaps and index on Project_Number and/or Segment1 will reduce query time.

Comment: I will have to request these to be created (I don't have permissions) other than this, do you see other possible improvement in my code? (other than the oracle query)

Comment: The speed is usually based on the driver you are using in the connection string.  Some driver are faster than others.  For example OLEDB was suppose to be a replacement for ODBC.  ODBC had issues with compatibility and OLEDB was suppose to solve the incompatibility issue.  But OLEDB was so slow many vendors went back to ODBC.

Comment: How do I check my driver here? since I'm not specifying it in the connection? @jdw

Comment: You are using a managed Oracle driver, as you should from .NET. OLEDB and ODBC are primarily for native (unmanaged) code.